# Can I simulate what an image will look like on a Smartwatch by using Chrome Developer Tools and Emulation?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, emulation

If I have a webpage that has an image (regular ), if I use the Developer Tools in Chrome, choose emulation, and then adjust my resolution to that of the watch, say 144x168, will that give me a fairly accurate representation of  what an image will look like on the smartwatch?

Edit:  I wanted to put smartwatch for a tag, but it apparently doesn't exist.  It changes it to sony-smartwatch, which is not relevant here.